# Bump Allocator in Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, memory-management

Here is my code for implementing a linked list with custom allocators (the standard malloc/free and a simple bump allocator). I appreciate any comments or critiques about architecture, formatting, and anything in between. There are a number of files so I am very appreciative of comments even concerning singular functions. I am especially interested in opinions on my bump allocator implementation and on my "polymorphism" hack with the `MemAlloc` struct. The code has been run with gcc and valgrind.

The code is organized into three header files and three source files, placed in the `inc` and `src` folders, respectively. Here is the Makefile I use for building which is located in the root directory. It creates a `bin` folder which contains the main executable.

**Makefile**

```
CC      := gcc
CCFLAGS := -g3 -g \
       -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wconversion -Wdouble-promotion \
       -Werror -Wextra -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Wshadow \
       -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wundef \
       -fno-common -fPIC
CLIB    := -lm

TARGET  := main
BIN_DIR := bin
OBJ_DIR := build
INC_DIR := inc
SRC_DIR := src

SRC     := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJ     := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/*.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))


$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET):   $(OBJ) | bin
            $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -I$(INC_DIR) $(CLIB)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:     $(SRC_DIR)/%.c | build
            $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $^ -I$(INC_DIR) $(CLIB)

bin:
            mkdir $(BIN_DIR)

build:
            mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)

clean:
            rm -fr $(OBJ_DIR)
            rm -fr $(BIN_DIR)
            rm -fr perf.data perf.data.old
            rm -fr gmon.out gprof.txt
            rm -fr vg_logfile.out
```

**memory.h**

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H
#define MEMORY_H

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct MemAlloc MemAlloc;
typedef struct MemBump MemBump;
typedef struct MemMalloc MemMalloc;

typedef enum { BUMP, MALLOC, } MemAllocType;

/**
A memory allocator that is able to allocate and free.
*/
struct MemAlloc {
  void* (*alloc)(MemAlloc*, size_t);
  void (*free)(MemAlloc*, void*);
  MemAllocType type;
};

/**
Construct a memory allocator.

type: the type of allocator
size: the size in bytes to allocate

Note: MALLOC allocator does not use the size parameter.
*/
MemAlloc*
mem_alloc_create(MemAllocType type, size_t size);

/**
Destroy a memory allocator.

allocator: the allocator to destroy
*/
void
mem_alloc_destroy(MemAlloc* allocator);

#endif
```

**memory.c**

```
#include "memory.h"

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// -----
// BUMP
// -----

/**
A bump allocator that divides its memory into used and unused segments.

NOTE: freeing memory in a bump allocator does nothing

   [  unused   |   used   ]
   ^           ^          ^
   head        ptr        tail

   (ptr moves in <-- direction)
*/
struct MemBump {
  void* (*alloc)(MemBump*, size_t);
  void (*free)(MemBump*, void*);
  MemAllocType type;
  
  size_t num_allocs;  
  size_t capacity;
  void* head;
  void* tail;
  void* ptr;  
};

void*
mem_bump_alloc(MemBump* allocator, size_t size) {
  if (size > allocator->capacity) return NULL;
  void* ptr = (char*) allocator->ptr - size;
  size_t word_size = (size_t) sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT;
  if (size >= word_size) {
    // NOTE(matt): this bit twiddling assumes align is a power of 2
    // https://fitzgeraldnick.com/2019/11/01/always-allocator-downwards.html
    ptr = (void*) ((uintptr_t) ptr & ~(word_size - 1));
  }
  if (ptr < allocator->head) return NULL;
  allocator->capacity -= (size_t) ((uintptr_t) allocator->ptr - (uintptr_t) ptr);
  allocator->num_allocs++;
  allocator->ptr = ptr;
  return ptr;
}

void
mem_bump_free(MemBump* allocator, void* ptr) {
  (void) allocator;
  (void) ptr;
}

MemBump*
mem_bump_create(size_t capacity) {
  // NOTE(matt): this capacity should be at least the size of a CPU word
  MemBump* allocator = malloc(sizeof(*allocator));
  if (!allocator) return NULL;
  allocator->capacity = capacity;
  allocator->num_allocs = 0;
  allocator->head = malloc(capacity);
  if (!allocator->head) { free(allocator); return NULL; }
  allocator->tail = (char*) allocator->head + capacity;
  allocator->ptr = allocator->tail;
  
  allocator->alloc = mem_bump_alloc;
  allocator->free = mem_bump_free;
  allocator->type = BUMP;
  return allocator;
}

void
mem_bump_destroy(MemBump* allocator) {
  free(allocator->head);
  free(allocator);
}

// -----
// MALLOC
// -----

/**
An allocator that uses the standard malloc and free.
*/
struct MemMalloc {
  void* (*alloc)(MemMalloc*, size_t);
  void (*free)(MemMalloc*, void*);
  MemAllocType type;
  
  size_t num_allocs;
};

void*
mem_malloc_alloc(MemMalloc* allocator, size_t size) {
  void* ptr = malloc(size);
  if (!ptr) return NULL;
  allocator->num_allocs++;
  return ptr;
}

void
mem_malloc_free(MemMalloc* allocator, void* ptr) {
  allocator->num_allocs--;
  free(ptr);
}

MemMalloc*
mem_malloc_create(void) {
  MemMalloc* allocator = malloc(sizeof(*allocator));
  if (!allocator) return NULL;
  allocator->num_allocs = 0;
  
  allocator->alloc = mem_malloc_alloc;
  allocator->free = mem_malloc_free;
  allocator->type = MALLOC;
  return allocator;
}

void
mem_malloc_destroy(MemMalloc* allocator) {
  free(allocator);
}

// -----
// INTERFACE
// -----

MemAlloc*
mem_alloc_create(MemAllocType type, size_t size) {
  switch(type) {
  case BUMP:
    return (MemAlloc*) mem_bump_create(size);
  case MALLOC:
    return (MemAlloc*) mem_malloc_create();
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create memory allocator.\n");
    return NULL;
  }
}

void
mem_alloc_destroy(MemAlloc* allocator) {
  switch(allocator->type) {
  case BUMP:
    mem_bump_destroy((MemBump*) allocator);
    break;
  case MALLOC:
    mem_malloc_destroy((MemMalloc*) allocator);
    break;
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to destroy memory allocator.\n");
    break;
  }
}
```

**linkedlist.h**

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include "linkedlist.h"

#include "memory.h"

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
typedef struct LinkedListNode LinkedListNode;

struct LinkedList {  
  LinkedListNode* first;
  LinkedListNode* last;
  size_t length;
  
  MemAlloc* allocator;
};

struct LinkedListNode {
  void* data;
  LinkedListNode* next;
};

/**
Append (to the end) of the linked list.
*/
void*
linkedlist_append(LinkedList* ll, void* data);

/**
Index the linked list and return the data.
*/
void*
linkedlist_at(const LinkedList* ll, size_t i);

/**
Create a linked list.
*/
LinkedList*
linkedlist_create(MemAlloc* allocator);

/**
Destroy a linked list.
*/
void
linkedlist_destroy(LinkedList* ll);

/**
Return the length of a linked list.
*/
size_t
linkedlist_length(const LinkedList* ll);

/**
Prepend (to the beginning) of the linked list.
*/
void*
linkedlist_prepend(LinkedList* ll, void* data);

/**
Print the contents of the linked list.
*/
void
linkedlist_print(const LinkedList* ll, void (*print)(void*));

#endif
```

**linkedlist.c**

```
#include "linkedlist.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void*
linkedlist_append(LinkedList* ll, void* data) {
  LinkedListNode* node = ll->allocator->alloc(ll->allocator, sizeof(*node));
  if (!node) return NULL;
  
  node->data = data;
  node->next = NULL;
  
  if (ll->first == NULL) {
    ll->first = node;
    ll->last = node;
  }
  else {
    ll->last->next = node;
    ll->last = node;
  }
  ll->length++;
  return data;
}

void*
linkedlist_at(const LinkedList* ll, size_t i) {
  if (ll->length <= i) return NULL;
  
  LinkedListNode* node = ll->first;
  if (!node) return NULL;
  
  while (i > 0) {
    node = node->next;
    i--;
  }
  return node->data;
}

LinkedList*
linkedlist_create(MemAlloc* allocator) {
  LinkedList* ll = allocator->alloc(allocator, sizeof(*ll));
  if (!ll) return NULL;
  ll->first = NULL;
  ll->last = NULL;
  ll->length = 0;
  ll->allocator = allocator;
  return ll;
}

void
linkedlist_destroy(LinkedList* ll) {
  LinkedListNode* node = ll->first;
  while (node != NULL) {
    LinkedListNode* tmp = node->next;
    ll->allocator->free(ll->allocator, node);
    node = tmp;
  }
  ll->allocator->free(ll->allocator, ll);
}

size_t
linkedlist_length(const LinkedList* ll) {
  return ll->length;
}

void*
linkedlist_prepend(LinkedList* ll, void* data) {
  LinkedListNode* node = ll->allocator->alloc(ll->allocator, sizeof(*node));
  if (!node) return NULL;
  
  node->data = data;
  node->next = NULL;
  
  if (ll->first == NULL) {
    ll->first = node;
    ll->last = node;
  }
  else {
    node->next = ll->first;
    ll->first = node;
  }
  ll->length++;
  return data;
}

void
linkedlist_print(const LinkedList* ll, void (*print)(void*)) {
  LinkedListNode* node = ll->first;
  if (node == NULL) { return; }
  print(node->data);
  while (node->next != NULL) {
    print(node->next->data);
    node = node->next;
  }
}
```

**print.h**

```
#ifndef PRINT_H
#define PRINT_H

#include <stdio.h>

void print_float(void* data) { printf("%g\n", *((double*) data)); }
void print_int(void* data) { printf("%d\n", *((int*) data)); }

#endif
```

**main.c**

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include "memory.h"
#include "print.h"

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

double
time_bump(size_t num_nodes) {
  clock_t begin = clock();

  size_t memory_size = sizeof(LinkedList) + num_nodes * sizeof(LinkedListNode);
  
  MemAlloc* allocator = mem_alloc_create(BUMP, memory_size);
  
  if (!allocator) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create bump allocator.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  
  int a = 4;
  LinkedList* ll = linkedlist_create((MemAlloc*) allocator);
  if (!ll) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create linked list.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++) {
    if (!linkedlist_append(ll, &a)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to append node.\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  linkedlist_destroy(ll);
  mem_alloc_destroy(allocator);
  
  clock_t end = clock();
  double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  return time_spent;
}

double
time_malloc(size_t num_nodes) {
  clock_t begin = clock();
  
  MemAlloc* allocator = mem_alloc_create(MALLOC, 0);
  
  if (!allocator) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create malloc allocator.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  
  int a = 4;
  LinkedList* ll = linkedlist_create((MemAlloc*) allocator);
  if (!ll) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create linked list.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++) {
    if (!linkedlist_append(ll, &a)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to append node.\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  linkedlist_destroy(ll);
  mem_alloc_destroy(allocator);
  
  clock_t end = clock();
  double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  return time_spent;
}

int
main(void) {
  // Compare the performance of the regular allocation (malloc and free) to
  // the performance of a simple bump allocator.  
  // Both trials simply insert integer pointers into a linked list.
  
  size_t num_nodes = 1 * pow(10, 5);
  printf("Malloc: %.10f\n", time_malloc(num_nodes));
  printf("Bump: %.10f\n", time_bump(num_nodes));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Makefile variables

You use `$(BIN_DIR)`, `$@` and `$^` correctly here:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET):   $(OBJ) | bin
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -I$(INC_DIR) $(CLIB)
```

but not here:

```
bin:
        mkdir $(BIN_DIR)
```

This should be:

```
$(BIN_DIR):
    mkdir $@
```

### Conflation of tags and definitions

I typically recommend against naming these the same (i.e. `MemAlloc` and `MemAlloc`). One way to differentiate them is to name the tag `MemAllocTag`.

### Void casting

This:

```
void
mem_bump_free(MemBump* allocator, void* ptr) {
  (void) allocator;
  (void) ptr;
}
```

is foreign syntax to me; apparently it's a [hack to tell the compiler to suppress warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34289000/313768). But why doesn't `mem_bump_free` do anything?

### C99 struct sugar

For known initialization values, this:

```
  MemBump* allocator = malloc(sizeof(*allocator));
  if (!allocator) return NULL;
  allocator->capacity = capacity;
  allocator->num_allocs = 0;
  allocator->head = malloc(capacity);
  if (!allocator->head) { free(allocator); return NULL; }
  allocator->tail = (char*) allocator->head + capacity;
  allocator->ptr = allocator->tail;
  
  allocator->alloc = mem_bump_alloc;
  allocator->free = mem_bump_free;
  allocator->type = BUMP;
```

can be made somewhat nicer:

```
  MemBump *allocator = malloc(sizeof(MemBump));
  if (!allocator) return NULL;

  *allocator = (MemBump) {
    .capacity = capacity,
    .num_allocs = 0,
    .alloc = mem_bump_alloc,
    .free = mem_bump_free,
    .type = BUMP,
    .head = malloc(capacity)
  }

  if (!allocator->head) { free(allocator); return NULL; }

  allocator->tail = (char*) allocator->head + capacity;
  allocator->ptr = allocator->tail;
```

### Named signature pointer parameters

For better code self-documentation, consider adding parameter names to

```
void* (*alloc)(MemMalloc*, size_t);
void (*free)(MemMalloc*, void*);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice -- the struct initialization looks fantastic! Could you expound a bit on why you don't like to conflate tags?

Comment: Generally speaking, even if the compiler thinks your usage is unambiguous, to human eyes those names are ambiguous. It's safer and more easily understandable to simply use different names.